# Invalid merchant - payments to this merchant are not allowed (invalid clientId )

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I am doing iOS Paypal payment gateway integration , when i add my live account API credential i am getting error message like **`“Invalid merchant “`** . But it works with Sandbox API Credential .Can anyone help me to solve this error please .

For your reference please find attached screenshot.

My Simulator Screenshot :

[image]

**Error Message in my Xcode Debug Area :**

```
 {

        "error_description" = "Client Authentication failed";

    }

)
2016-02-01 14:39:36.881 isaaf[3620:1815188] PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: invalid_client - System error (invalid_client). Please try again later. (401) | PayPal Debug-ID: 49b6d1c71e66a [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.10.2] | Details: (
     {

            "error_description" = "Client Authentication failed";

        }
```

**My Paypal Account Screenshot :**

[image]

Comment: i think your live payments for credit card are not Enabled

Comment: @ArslanAsim , I am trying to enable it but it says "Note: Direct credit card processing is not available for you when using REST APIs. Your live credentials are inoperable for direct credit card processing for your country but your test credentials are enabled for sandbox testing.".

Comment: have you changed environment?

Comment: yes i changed it , but so far no luck .

Comment: and using credit card for payment ?

Comment: plus i've seen that your screen shot says it's sandbox, can you please share some code, where you are setting every thing

Comment: Getting same error, Tried many things, But no LUCK