# Does it possible to test iOS app using PayPal Live Credentials(clientID & sandboxID) before submitting app in Apple App Store?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sorry to ask this question. Because there were no.of links available related to this question but my intention is little bit different that's the reason only i posted this Question here:

Does it possible to check iOS app using PayPal Live Credentials before submitting app in Apple App Store?

The thing is that in Apple side there were 2 concepts like **Push Notification** & **In-App Purchase** (**Production not in Development**) we can't check in testing time. I feel PayPal also same. But i am little bit doubt in that.....

By using:  https://simicart.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/214860237-How-To-Obtain-API-Client-ID-And-Secret-Key-Within-Your-Paypal-Account-

I have integrated paypal in my app and it works fine in sandbox but now i want to make live run on live app id so what i need to do ?

Here i am facing an issue same as: [Invalid merchant - payments to this merchant are not allowed (invalid clientId )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310434/invalid-merchant-payments-to-this-merchant-are-not-allowed-invalid-clientid)

NOTE: I already red PayPal iOS SDK integration process in developer.paypal.com also

(1) " Log in to the PayPal Developer website using the credentials of the PayPal account registered to the application owner. Note that the PayPal account associated with the application must be a verified Premier or verified Business account."

I did same thing. Now i am using valid LIVE Client id & Sandbox Key.

In **ANDROID**:
  LIVE credentials are working fine

In **iOS:** It was saying an error like what ever i mentioned on top?

How can i resolve this issue? Can you please help me out.

Here i Use code like:

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark -- connectToPayPalBtnClicked
- (IBAction)connectToPayPalBtnClicked:(id)sender {
 //    // Create a PayPalPayment
  PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
   payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"10.95"];
   //we recommend limiting transactions to currencies supported by both payment types. Currently these are: USD, GBP, CAD, EUR, JPY.
   payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
   payment.shortDescription = @"Awesome saws";

   // Check whether payment is processable.
  if (!payment.processable) {
      // If, for example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was empty, then
    // this payment would not be processable. You would want to handle that here.
 }
 /*
   For Test Account purpose
     [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{
                                                       PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : PayPalClienKey}];
 */
[PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"AU2qoYgXhfghgfhgfhfghhNS_QYjTSMV_LS4RmG-qbPGdXODlvJXuSE5jXQRAeJEwPvh6h4C",
                                                       PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"ELQN7GqTJZDCH3Qfr17wyhfghfghgfhhg9esR9fyJ9prL6xKfFURMoAK0PZw0scTB5I6Un  "}];

  #ifdef CONFIGURATION_ReleaseLive
   [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentProduction];
 #else
  [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentSandbox]; // PayPalEnvironmentSandbox ?
#endif
  [self setPayPalConfig:[[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init]];
  [[self payPalConfig] setAcceptCreditCards:YES];
   [[self payPalConfig] setPayPalShippingAddressOption:PayPalShippingAddressOptionNone];
   [[self payPalConfig] setLanguageOrLocale:[NSLocale preferredLanguages][0]];
   // Create a PayPalPaymentViewController.
    PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController;
     paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment
                                                                configuration:self.payPalConfiguration
                                                                    delegate:self];

   // Present the PayPalPaymentViewController.
    [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
 }

#pragma mark - PayPalPaymentDelegate methods
- (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController
             didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
     NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Success!");
    // Payment was processed successfully; send to server for verification and fulfillment.
    [self verifyCompletedPayment:completedPayment];

    // Dismiss the PayPalPaymentViewController.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }

   - (void)payPalPaymentDidCancel:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController {
     NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Canceled");
    // The payment was canceled; dismiss the PayPalPaymentViewController.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  }
  - (void)verifyCompletedPayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
   // Send the entire confirmation dictionary
      confirmation = [NSJSONSerialization  dataWithJSONObject:completedPayment.confirmation
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:nil];
     NSLog(@"Here is your proof of payment:\n\n%@\n\nSend this to your server for confirmation and fulfillment.", completedPayment.confirmation);

      // Send confirmation to your server; your server should verify the proof of payment
      // and give the user their goods or services. If the server is not reachable, save
     // the confirmation and try again later.
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can test the live credentials.  It does not require the same permissions from Apple as push notifications or in-app purchases.

Aside from adding the production clientID in your appDelegate, you'll need to add this line in the viewWillAppear section of whichever viewController is loading the PayPalPaymentViewController:

```
[PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentProduction];
```

Now when the PayPal check out view is loaded you can use your own live Paypal account (be careful because if you make a payment it will be for real money) instead of the developer accounts that you set up.

Comment: ThanQ @Ryan Friedman. If you don't mine how can i get Client Live Production Key and can you please share me some sample code